# Django not inserting data into database when I execute subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am using django and inserting data into database and downloading images. When I call the function it works fine but it blocks the main thread. To execute the process in the background  I'm using :

views.py:

class get_all_data(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

```
subprocess.Popen(
            ['python get_images.py --data=data'],
            close_fds=True,
            shell = True
        )
```

But when I call:

`python get_images.py(data="data")`

it works fine but it runs on the main thread.

How can I fix it ? BTW I'm using **python 2.7**.

Note: Please don't suggest Celery . I'm looking for something which runs the task async or any other alternative.

I'm using the following code to insert into my db:

**get_images.py:**

```
from models import Test


        def get_image_all():

            #get data from server
            insert_to_Test(data="data")



        if __name__ == "__main__":
            import argparse
            from  .models import Test
            import django
            django.setup()

            parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
            parser.add_argument('--from_date')
            parser.add_argument('--data')
            parser.add_argument('--execute', type=bool, default=False)
            args = parser.parse_args()
            print "args", args
            get_image_all(**vars(args))
```

When I call subprocess.Popen then it does not insert data into my db but If I execute it by call the function then it inserts the data to db. Why does that happen?

Comment: `python get_images.py(data="data")` What kind of shell are you using? This is definitely a syntax error under bash.

Comment: Celery *is* the way to run the task async. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @freakish I'm calling the method in this way and not using the shell : python get_images.py(data="data"). )Only the code with Popen is within a shell.

Comment: Show the content of `get_images.py` I suspect you're using things in it that would only run if executed inside a Django context (e.g. importing models)

Comment: @bakkal I'm sorry I had added the code under the wrong file. I've updated all changes. Please take a look :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threading in Django is not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126586/threading-in-django-is-not-working-in-production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, import and use Django models ***after*** `django.setup()`
- Second, make sure the environment the spawn process runs in is correct, mainly make sure you use the right **Python interpreter in the right virtualenv** (if you use it), and make sure the process runs in the correct **working directory**

Sample code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import argparse
    import django
    django.setup()

    from  .models import Test

    # Parse args
    # Use Django models
```

Next you need to make sure `subprocess` runs in the correct working directory, and activates your Python virtualenv (if any), roughly something like below:

```
subprocess.Popen(
    '/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python get_images.py --data=data', 
    cwd='/path/to/project/working_directory/',
    shell=True
)
```

Comment: I get this error now :  raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
subprocess.Popen(
            ['python get_images.py(data=data)'],
            close_fds=True,
            shell = True
        )
```