# How to use sleep effectively in python 2.7 without increasing the active threads

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I need to recursively call API request if an error occurs after making it sleep for few seconds. But I cannot allow to sleep because only limited number of active threads are allowed in Apache. So there comes situation like all active threads are in the sleep state. How can I handle this situation

currently, I am using like

```
from time import sleep
def api_request(flag=0):
    time_delay = 2**flag
    flag = flag + 1
    result = apicall()
    if result['status']="succes":
        return(result)
    else:
        if flag < 5:                
            sleep(time_delay)
            api_request(flag)
        else:
            print "api request failed"
```

I am looking alternative solution that won't sleep the thread but it calls the function after few seconds

Comment: Any approach to do what you want would involve some sort of a callback which can only be invoked via a signal which again, requires > 1 thread...

Comment: I just want to avoid sleeping threads, It's a background process. Can we queue properly if we try to invoke using signals? Can you please provide a sample of it.

Comment: What sort of signals are you talking about? UNIX signals can't be used when hosting a WSGI application under Apache with mod_wsgi and they should in general be avoided with any WSGI server as arbitrary use of UNIX signals can interfere with the operation of the WSGI server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threading in Django is not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126586/threading-in-django-is-not-working-in-production)