# Django form not saving to DB

Tags: python, django

I tired using the formset to create a form but the form is not saving. The form is imported from my model and four forms has foreign key to the main form. My terminal looks like this: [12/Jun/2017 22:26:20] "POST /model_form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 25267

My view:

```
    def careerForm(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form1 = ModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            formset1 = ModelFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            formset2 = ModelFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            formset3 = ModelFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            formset4 = ModelFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            if form1.is_valid() and formset1.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid() and formset3.is_valid() and formset4.is_valid():
                message = "Thank you"
                career.vacancy =  get_object_or_404(Vacancy, pk = request.POST.get('vacancy'))

                form1.save()
                formset1.save()
                formset2.save()
                formset3.save()
                formset4.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect('successful')

            else:
                message = "Something went wrong"

            context = { 'message': message }
            return render(request, 'library/careerForm.html', context)
        else:        
            form1 = ModelForm()
            formset1 = ModelFormSet()
            formset2 = ModelFormSet()
            formset3 = ModelFormSet()
            formset4 = ModelFormSet()
        context = { 'form1': form1, 'formset1': formset1, 'formset2': formset2, 'formset3': formset3, 'formset4': formset4 }
return render(request, 'library/careerForm.html', context)
```

form.py

```
    class ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Model
            fields = '__all__'
            exclude = ['is_visible']

    ModelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Model, Model_formset, fields = '__all__', exclude = ['is_visible'])
    ModelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Model, Model_formset, fields = '__all__', exclude = ['is_visible'])
    ModelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Model, Model_formset, fields = '__all__', exclude = ['is_visible'])
    ModelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Model, Model_formset, fields = '__all__', exclude = ['is_visible'])
```

templete

```
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'peruse:careerForm' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
```

output result on my browser

```
    [output result on my browser][1]
```

Comment: add the form and the template but we need just the `<form ....>...</form>` part. Maybe you forgot to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'`. Did you check if the form is valid at any point? try `print("test")` under `if form1.is_valid() ....`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threading in Django is not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126586/threading-in-django-is-not-working-in-production)